# Inconsistent CSS behavior: 'display' and 'float' -- need advice

Tags: css, css-float

I'm in the midst of the HTML5/CSS/JavaScript learning curve and have hit a wall.

My goal is to create a form. In the process of executing this seemingly simple task, I've created a confusing monstrosity that displays perfectly in Firefox and IE, but appears as a jumbled mess in Chrome and Safari. I've written some sample code that illustrates my problem. Consider this three line form that has two text fields for username and password, and a checkbox to indicate whether or not the theme from 'Sanford and Son' should play during the user's session.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            form label{
                float: left;
                clear: left;
                text-align: right;
                margin-right: 10px;
                width: 110px;
            }
            form input{
                display: block;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                padding: 0px .2em;
                outline: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="loginPopup">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>

                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>

                <label for="sanford">Sanford Theme:</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="sanford" name="sanford"/>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Try viewing it in IE or Firefox and everything looks perfect. Now try viewing it in Chrome or Safari. The 'sanford' checkbox appears *underneath* its label. Not good. The checkbox is obviously supposed to appear to the *right* of the label. What's even more perplexing is that if I replace the checkbox with some other input (e.g. text, radio, etc.), everything appears properly in all browsers. This problem seems limited to the checkbox.

I can't wrap my head around what's going on here. The 'Sanford' label is floated to the left so presumably the checkbox should flow to the immediate right of that label -- and in fact that's exactly what happens in Firefox/IE… so why not in Chrome/Safari?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I posted the code to the Fiddle site as requested: http://jsfiddle.net/ChadDecker/FyNZw/

Comment: Create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of this code, it will make more sense

Comment: Ok I created a Fiddle account and posted the code here. You will see the checkbox appears correctly when viewed in IE/Firefox but incorrectly in Chrome/Safari... http://jsfiddle.net/ChadDecker/FyNZw/

Answer (score 2):

Float is tricky. If one element is floated, the others have to be floated or it will be all screwed up. So you must float every element and adjust with padding/margin as necessary. What you may want to try also is using:

```
position: absolute;
```

and also using z-index which tells the page what items to display over top of the other:

```
z-index: 0;
```

**EDIT**

Your form on JSFiddle: It's all designed wrong in my opinion. You shouldn't be using `form.input` because since the checkbox field is considered a form of input, hence `<input` then it gets the properties from `form.input` style. I made a simple class to show you called box:

http://jsfiddle.net/FyNZw/2/

Comment: I've read about the z-index property but I doubt it's ever appropriate to have a checkbox appear over its own label. I added a JSFiddle link to my original post so you can see what I mean. Checkbox appears appropriately (to the right of label) in IE/Firefox and fails in Chrome/Safari. Regarding absolute positioning... I can see how that would work, but is that really how forms are designed? By specifying in absolute terms, pixel by pixel, where each field should go with no document flow? I figured there'd be an easier way but maybe not..

Comment: Float is not that tricky and making blanket statements like, _"If one element is floated, the others have to be floated or it will be all screwed up"_ is, at best, misleading and not very technical.